# Clear all breakpoints in Node debugger

Tags: node.js, node-debugger

I set a new breakpoint using `setBreakpoint(3)` (where `3` is the line number).

If I want to remove it I can use `clearBreakpoint(3)`, but how can I remove **all breakpoints** added this way?

Answer (score 1):

This is not ideal, but, it works. You can use the following - I left it as a one-liner so you can copy it easily. Note: the output is ugly, but it works.

`var i=500; while(i--){clearBreakpoint('/path/to/file/with/breakpoints.js', i); }`

Of course, first make sure you set `i` = to the number of lines in your file or at least the last one with a breakpoint on it, and, your own file path. Note: you may not need to specify file name if you didn't specify it when you set the breakpoint.

Expanded for readability:

```
var i = 500;  // number of lines in file

while(i--){
   // in my experiments, you *must* use the filename, but
   // I had defined my filename when I set the breakpoints
   clearBreakpoint('/path/to/file/with/breakpoints.js', i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - was having trouble clearing breakpoints.  Pretty crazy that you need to specify the whole path.